# Get the URL of a server

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I am using flask and flask email for sending an email. When I work on I used the localhost as a base url. I deployed it on the server and email sent is still showing with localhost address.
For example

```
base_url = "http://localhost:0.0.0.6465"
url=base_url+'/login'
```

I sent an email(i am using flask-mail) with the url and I can login with the url.

With the same script when I deployed on the server I am getting with same localhost address.I need the server URL should be the base url.
To debug this I tried

```
url=request.base_url+'/login'
```

I am getting 404 error in the browser if I use this. I dont want to change the initializtion of base_url because I have to use both in the local as well as in the server.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the URL to the currently running app through `request.host_url`. But what you *really* want to to do to get an external URL to a specific part of your application, is to use `url_for` as you'd do when referencing your regular endpoints, but with the parameter `_external=True`:

Given that you have:

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    ....
```

You can generate an external URL by using:

```
from flask import (
    url_for,
)

...

url = url_for('login', _external=True)
```

This will also take into account any proxies in front of your application if you need that, as long as you've used the `ProxyFix` middleware when setting up your `app` object.

Since this uses the same mechanism as Flask uses when generating URLs between different pages, it should behave just as you want - i.e. it'll work both on `localhost` and on the remote host.

Comment: The generated url has to sent via email. So I cant use url_for.am I correct?

Comment: No, that doesn't matter. The `url_for` will be called in your application, and will give the URL to the controller you're giving it, in the current environment the application is running in. If you're running the application on localhost, it'll give localhost in the URL - if you're running it on a remote site, it'll give the remote site URL used to access the controller. That's the point - it'll give you the url to the controller _in the environment it is currently running_. Sending it through email doesn't matter - it just gives the URL to the controller you want to link to.